# Difference between Google Fit API and ActivityRecognitionAPI

Tags: android, api, android-sensors, google-fit, activity-recognition

I'm studying how to get the user activity from the android sensors and I have a question... Whats the difference between ***Google Fit API*** and ***AcitivityRecognitionAPI*** ?

The *Google Fit API* is newer so it's better than *ActivityRecognitionAPI*? 
There's no relation between them?
Can anyone tell me where to found a great documentation or explanation of *ActivityRecognitionAPI*? Because de google developers website don't tell me everything I wanna know about this API...

Thanks! (And sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are totally unrelated, could be used together.

The ActivityRecognitionAPI attempts to figure out what you are doing: walking, sitting, driving in a car.

Fit is the name for Google's equivalent of HealthKit from Apple: comprehensive store for consolidated health information, like weight, height, blood pressure, vitamin doses, etc.

The docs are limited, all I found from google is the JavaDoc. This [thread](https://blacode.wordpress.com/2014/12/26/user-activity-recognition-through-new-activityrecognitionapi-in-android-activityrecognitionclient-deprecated/comment-page-1/) is really good. Look at the second code listing: you are going to get called back. Then you will figure out what the User started doing by passing the code into the switch statement.

Comment: Thanks Rob! 
So, **ActivityRecognitionAPI** isn't a ''piece'' of **Google Fit API**, right?

Comment: No, it's not part of the Fit API. It's part of Play Services, but they have rolled everything into that now. Ok, a lot of stuff.

Comment: Hmm... ok! And Rob, did you know any website that I can read the ***ActivityRecognitionAPI documentation***? Or some explanation of what it is?

Comment: Updated with a link to code that shows the activities.